# Passing a variable from ansible to powershell

Tags: powershell, ansible

How I can pass a variable from the playbook and it will be used powershell script in a remote host?
My playbook sample is:

`- name: SQL Configuration`
 `script: files/sql-config.ps1`

sql-config.ps1 execute on remote server and connect to SQL with $sql_pass.
I don't want to store the pass in the ps1 script for obvious reasons, so I'm trying to figure out how I can pass the value for $sql_pass directly from ansible.

I've tried to set up a the variable directly within vars: directory in the playbook but the remote server didn't received the variable so the script failed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmmm... So I need to create new task that will create the variable on the host first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, in your sql-config.ps1 you need first something like:

```
param 
( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
        [string]$sql_pass
)
```

Then, from your playbook, call the script like:

```
- name: SQL Configuration  script: files/sql-config.ps1 --sql_pass "{{ password }}"
```

Save your password under an ansible-vault as a variable:

Check [Ansible Documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/vault.html)